# Magento show Product Into Navigation MenuBar?

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to add products into navigation menubar?

I want to show product image, name, description into navigation menu bar.

Comment: Hi @renishkhunt...please ask question briefly ?and please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using magento default menu you can not display product into navigation menu but you can do that using your custome code. and then you also display product with image into navigation menubar